# Как передать managed handle в unmanaged function?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть некий менеджед хэндл, скажем, IntPtr Handle у некоего класса, наследуемого от Control (PictureBox).
Мне позарез нужно получить его Device Context. 
Но следующий код приводит к ошибке:

```
HandleRef handle = GetDC(cpb1.Handle);
```

Если какая-нибудь функция\фабрика\конвертер, позаоляющая безопасно привести типы\выполнить преобразование?

Comment: Эээ... WPF или Winforms? Или может быть Silverlight?

Comment: >Мне позарез нужно

курсач?))

Comment: Ага...    ....

Comment: А зачем вам? Есть имплементация на MFC, а учить WinForms неохота?

ЗЫ: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4759646/276994

Comment: Нет, у меня проект на си шарпе. MFC уже кстати deprecated в 12 студии

Comment: > MFC уже кстати deprecated в 12 студии
Кто Вам такую глупость сказал?)

По теме. Что есть GetDC у вас, extern? Как задекларирована?

Comment: Хм, а зачем вам тогда DC? Обычно такого хотеться не должно, может, вы что-то делаете не так? Расскажите, какую проблему вы решаете.

---
И кстати, почему ретроградский Winforms вместо прогрессивного WPF?

Comment: [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern HandleRef GetDC(IntPtr hwnd);

Comment: Вполне разумную вещь оно Вам говорит, кстати...
IntPtr в декларировании используйте в качестве возвращаемого типа...

Ну и как правильно спрашивает @VladD, а что собственно пытаетесь делать?

Comment: VlaD, с преогромным удовольствием рассказываю. Необходимо чтобы на форму можно было загружать картинки, масштабировать их, вращать как душе угодно, и при этом все это должно поддерживать прозрачность. 
Ретроградский Winforms использую потому что паттерн MVVM я не осилил, да и нет времени уже изучать WPF. Пробовал играться с Direct2D но и на этом пути меня постигли не удачи. Что я нашел это проджект razorgdipainter на codeplex, где чувак нереально быстро рисует в контрол что угодно с помощью SetDiBitsDevice. Вот собственно и хочу заюзать эту функцию. А ей нужен HDC.

Comment: @SoloMio: А вы бы выучили прогрессивный WPF, там прозрачность, вращение и масштабирование через Direct3D из коробки в 2 (прописью: две) строчки. Курсач от этого может быть и не выиграет, а вот ваша карьера разработчика очень даже.

Comment: @SoloMio: вот вам полное решение на WPF: http://pastebin.com/sQi3fU4s Пишется за 5 минут параллельно с кофе, булочками и чатом.

ЗЫ: вот улучшенная версия: http://pastebin.com/hTTMZ6GN (не прыгает при вращении).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перекрыть OnPaint, где HDC на блюдечке...

Comment: оно там IntPtr, а нужен HandleRef...

Comment: Зачем Вам HandleRef?

Comment: Да и, кстати, никто Вам не мешает написать нечто такое:
    
    new HandleRef(this, IntPtr);